# Secure the communication between website and our RESTful web service

Tags: java, json, rest, tomcat, restful-authentication

we will have a website created by an outsourcing company, that website will send some information in JSON payload to our RESTful web service. The user will do login and authentication on that website, so we don't want to know the username and password of the user. And what we need is make sure the JSON where sent from is that trusted website then we will send back another JSON payload with including some info from us.

I am pretty new in the security area so I have googled a bit to find out we can use certification to encrytion/decrytion the message. But what will be the solution if we can identify the hack request in the first place and rejecting that request.

Comment: Simple, use HTTPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of your description, there are coming two things in my mind immediately:

1. Use an **SSL certificate**. That already ensures that your
   site is being transferred encrypted over the internet.
2. Use a **token** system. Tokens are widely used in payment solutions for example - as credit card data should never touch your own server. All tokens contain some secret information that are used to prove identity.
3. Use HTTP request headers eg. **Basic Auth**

For sure, you should have a SSL certificate. This adds already a lot of security to your site.

> But what will be the solution if we can identify the hack request in the first place and rejecting that request.

Well, you have answered it yourself. If you can detect it, reject it.

Comment: So the Http header basic authentication + SSL certification to encryt the payload looks like a good combination for our case. Just wondering the http basic authentication is using Base64 to encode the username and password, is that secure ? I mean the hacker still can hijack the request and decoded it.

Comment: Not necessarily. Basic Authentication is usually done with Base64 encoding. But if you want to, you can encrypt it as you want. For example with MD5 or anything else that comes to your mind. You can put everything in the request header. The more you do your own thing, the harder a attacker will have it to hijack your side. Hope that helps :D

Comment: Thanks Andreas, that helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to protect your restful service is something like basic auth.  The application making the rest call would provide a request header like

```
Authorization: Basic ZWx1c3VhcmlvOnlsYWNsYXZlde
```

This would not be a user-based solution, but a webapp to webapp solution.  All other requests would be unauthorized.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication